# CodeRefactoringProvider should generate new file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm starting exploring Roslyn finally and now I want to write a `CodeRefactoringProvider` that creates a new file instead of replacing code in the a current one. My current code simple renames a class like this:

```
[ExportCodeRefactoringProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof(TransportModelCodeRefactoringProvider)), Shared]
internal class TransportModelCodeRefactoringProvider : CodeRefactoringProvider
{
    private const string Title = "Make TransportModel class";

    public override sealed async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync(CodeRefactoringContext context)
    {
        var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var node = root.FindNode(context.Span);
        var classDeclaration = node as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
        if (classDeclaration == null)
        {
            // current node is not a class declaration
            return;
        }
        var action = CodeAction.Create(Title, token => MakeTransportModelAsync(context.Document, classDeclaration, token), Title);
        context.RegisterRefactoring(action);
    }

    private async Task<Document> MakeTransportModelAsync(Document document, ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {            
        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
        var newRoot = (CompilationUnitSyntax)root;
        var newName = classDeclaration.Identifier + "TransportModel";
        var newId = SyntaxFactory.Identifier(classDeclaration.Identifier.LeadingTrivia, SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken, newName, newName, classDeclaration.Identifier.TrailingTrivia);
        var newClass = classDeclaration.ReplaceToken(classDeclaration.Identifier, newId);
        newRoot = newRoot.ReplaceNode(classDeclaration, newClass).NormalizeWhitespace();
        var result = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
        return result;            
    }
}
```

I found an overload to `CodeAction.Create` which accepts a `Task<Solution>` which I found interesting but then I don't know how to get the solution and/or project for the current document.

Answer (score 3):

Call the [other overload](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/CodeActions/CodeAction.cs,317) of `CodeAction.Create`, which takes a delegate that returns a `Solution`.

You can then return a `Solution` based on `context.Document.Project.Solution` with a new document added.